# URLs not clickable in Django

Tags: python, django, url

I apologize if this generic question is a repeat, although I havent seen it on here.

[having followed django tutorial] I have my index view defined as

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

and the index html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

but my `http://localhost:8000/polls/` just returns a non-clickable list of  Question.objects.all() ((not even 'bulleted' like the tutorial states they should appear))

what do I need to add in order to make (a URL in general) like this point to the actual question?

urls.py

`urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    # ex: /polls/5/analysis
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/analysis/$', views.analysis, name='analysis'),
)`

and here is the output of the `http://localhost:8000/polls/`

Was published recently?, happy?, WHATS UP?

`view-source:http://localhost:8000/polls/` returns

Was published recently?, happy?, WHATS UP?

Comment: i dont know what that means

Comment: Have you looked at the source of the page to see what it actually *is* generating yet?

Comment: from my admin page I have created 3 questions with choices.  I suppose I havent explicitly defined a path for each question/choice set that the clickable url would point to, but Im not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Can you post the page source of `http://localhost:8000/polls/`? `Right click -> View Page Source`

Comment: Right click in your browser window or CTRL+U

Comment: i had already done that.  I added it again above though

Answer (score 0):

Your `urls.py` file specifies the url patterns used by your application as well as the *keywords* that can be passed in an url. Post your `urls.py` and the html output of a page (render the page where these links are displayed and press ctrl+u to view the source) and perhaps someone will be able to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are escaping the template-block `{{ question.id }}`.

You should probably use `{% url "detail" question.id %}` instead of `/polls/{{ question.id }}/`.

You can find more information about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url